# Saving Images in Photoshop for App Development

Tags: ios, xcode

I was curious to know the best practice when saving images for my iPhone app project.

I know I have to make two images one for retina @ 326dpi and then one at 163dpi.

A lot of tuts I've read seem to save images as PNG regardless of if there's transparency - is that normal best practice? I would normally save as jpg if there is no transparency but keen to know what others do.

Finally - In Photoshop would you opt for 'Save as' or 'Save for Web'? I notice that on save for web - when you bring the image back into Photoshop and look at the dpi it is now set to 72dpi.

Sorry I'm not being too vague - just keen to hear your best practice approach.

Thanks

Shell

Comment: Most of the time when developing for web or applications, you're best off using pixels as units, e.g. create an image of 150x150 pixels and save a retina version at 300x300 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

DPI doesn't really matter. What matters is total pixels in each dimension. I have seen situations where Apple's code sets the scale of an image incorrectly if the DPI value in the image isn't correct.

The non-retina should be set to 72 DPI, and the retina should be 144 DPI.  I don't know where you're getting 326 and 163 dpi.

Apple's docs say that iOS is optimized for PNGs, and to use them in preference to JPEG. Xcode runs a moderate compression on the PNGs which is still very fast to load. JPEG decompression is a little slow, so you may introduce lag by using JPEGs.

That being said, we have a client who's app has massive numbers of images, and to reduce file sizes we saved them as JPEGs, and on newer hardware (iPhone 4s and later) they seem to load plenty fast.